# GetProcessIdOfThread without "windows.h"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I need to set priorities of threads manually, and I do this with `GetProcessIdOfThread`. Unfortunately, a 3rd party library requires me to build the code as `Use MFC in a Shared DLL` so that I can use `afx.h` for some dll trickery.

How can I use functions like `GetProcessIdOfThread` without `windows.h`?

I have tried to include `WinBase.h` but this throws out a lot of nonsense, compile errors.

Comment: Why can you use winbase.h, but not windows.h? The latter includes the former after some other headers.

Comment: I can't use `WinBase.h` due to compile time errors, `WinBase.h` requires #defines and such that are only present with `Windows.h`. I mentioned it to show some of the things I have tried.

Comment: I believe chris meant why exactly you can't just #include <windows.h>

Comment: I mean why would you try to include winbase.h when you say "without windows.h"? You'd have to replicate the portion of windows.h that comes before winbase.h to do that.

Comment: Why can't you use windows.h? I think MFC can be finicky with the order you include files, but that just means you have to put them in the right order.

Comment: If you can use mfc in your program without including "windows.h", you can definitely use GetProcessIdOfThread because mfc internally use lots of windows api itself. The "windows.h" is probably included inside the AFX header stuffs along the way down the chain. Just compile and tell us the error messages.

Comment: I have to agree with the above.  There's no reason why you can't use any Win32 API function just because you're using MFC.  Hundreds of well-known apps do exactly that.  You just need to figure out the header arrangement.  Maybe the better question is how to include windows.h so you can call whatever you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided your downstream linker settings are correct, you can simply add the function declaration to a project header file of your choosing.

Here's the original declaration in `WinBase.h`:

```
WINBASEAPI DWORD WINAPI GetProcessIdOfThread(HANDLE Thread);
```

If you're not including `Windows.h`, then you're not going to have most of the used preprocessor macros/definitions necessary for that particular declaration. If you're linking against the static library version of the CRT, this is the equivalent definition:

```
unsigned long __stdcall GetProcessIdOfThread(void *Thread);
```

If you're linking against the DLL version of the CRT, you'll need to prefix the declaration with `__declspec(dllimport)`:

```
__declspec(dllimport) unsigned long __stdcall GetProcessIdOfThread(void *Thread);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would approach this with putting a wrapper function in a separate .c(pp) file:

```
 #include <windows.h>


 DWORD GetPidFromThread(HANDLE thread)
 {
     return GetProcessIdOfThread(thread);
 }
```

You may still need to replace `DWORD` and `HANDLE` with some types that you can also use in your other files [and make a headerfile with the prototype of `GetPidFromThread`, but at least you can reasonably safely isolate those bits.